# how many rows in a column family in Cassandra can effect performance?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, data-modeling

I work in a massive weblog processing project with `apache Cassandra` , but i wonder that if i have too many rows in a columnfamily . Will This make my query slower ??

in my data , we have about 100 billion rows log / per day

if i partion them to many column family (as a day pattern like 20120627) is better ideal ???

Any one can give me a suggestion to modeling this data??

i intend to create only column family like that:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  KEY text PRIMARY KEY
) WITH
  comment='log' AND
  comparator=text
```

i want to process data at chunk of time stamp (ex process: 10:20 --> 10:30 data)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to create many column family But to use a composite key and work with columns.

The key can be with the form (day of the day:timestamp of the log) or (hour of the day:timestamp of the log) or (minute of the day:timestamp of the log)

Then to prevent conflict with logs with the same timestamp you can work with a super columns.

You can get more information about limitation on cassandra: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

Comment: thanks for your hellping, I try to use composite key in Casssandra but when i use Hector to insert data (with key is composite key) always failed , Can you give me any example use Hector to insert to a column family (which have composite key). :( :(

Comment: Sorry I don't know this library. I can just suggest to you http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[hector]+composite+key or to check the source code of this lib here: https://github.com/hector-client/hector